# Bucket policy to whitelist a specific IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have a bucket policy which looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/status": "INFECTED"
                },
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/ecs_task_role/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is something like this:

If the s3 object has a tag with the key-value `status=INFECTED`, then restrict access to the public, unless you are using this iam role `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecs_task_role`. So any system(container here) which assumes this iam role should be able to access the bucket contents regardless of what tag the objects in it has.

I've seen that my ecs tasks assume this role and its role arn then looks something like this: `arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/ecs_task_role/e7f2364b-c93d-4228-9259-1a59bdf2d201`.

So I've used the wildcard `StringNotLike` operator to whitelist the requests coming from my ecs tasks.

But for some reason this doesn't work. My ecs tasks are getting 403 access denied's when trying to download objects from the bucket with the tag `status: INFECTED`. What am I missing here? And more importantly, What do I need to change to make this access control logic work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Life is much simpler without using `Deny`.

It appears you have two requirements:

- Block public access for 'INFECTED' objects
- Grant access to the IAM Role

This can be broken down into two components:

- A Bucket Policy that grants access to non-INFECTED objects
- A policy on the IAM Role that grants access to the bucket (regardless of the metadata)

In the bucket policy, you should use `NotStringEquals` to check for the tag (that is, grant permission where that tag is *not* found). This limits the `Allow` without having to use a `Deny`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AllowNonInfected",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stack-woodstock/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/status": "INFECTED"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace NotSourceArn with [NotPrincipal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html)

This is how you’d reference an IAM role in the bucket policy.

Comment: But `NotPrincipal` doesn't support wildcard operators right? So How can I whitelist all the role arn's which assume `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecs_task_role`.  My ecs-tasks all have this random string attached to the end of the role arn.

Comment: The NotPrincipal would be the IAM role you want to use, and then you’d still use a deny. As in debt where not this principal :)

Comment: I'm sorry I've tried this and it doesn't work. Every ECS task has a different role arn(like `arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/ecs_task_role/0bf26e90-9c3b-462c-983e-db33087ed86c`). So  this principal based access control doesn't work as the role arn used in the `NotPrincipal` block wouldn't match for the different ECS tasks I have running.

Comment: It can also be an array, if you check the examples https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html :)

Comment: Yes, but i don't know anything about the random strings that get attached to the ecs tasks roles. It would be a brittle fix to hard code those assumed iam role arn's. I don't know when that'll change, or what if the ecs service decides to start new tasks, each with its own random string appended to the assumed role arn.

Comment: The principal should be able to be arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecs_task_role

Comment: Can you paste your policy?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecs_task_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/status": "INFECTED"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}